# "I have no name!" as user logging into Jenkins in a docker container that uses Tini

Tags: shell, unix, jenkins, ssh, docker

I'm currently using a Jenkins instance inside a [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/). 
This image happens to use [Tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) as PID 1. 
When I try open a shell into it with:

```
$ docker exec -it jenkins /bin/bash
```

I get this as username:

```
I have no name!@<container_id_hash>:/$
```

This is keeping me from using shell born ssh commands from Jenkins jobs that runs inside this container:

```
$ ssh
$ No user exists for uid 497
$ id
$ uid=497 gid=495 groups=495
```

I tried creating an user for that uid in /etc/passwd and also a group for that gid in /etc/group but it was a no deal!

I'm only able to run ssh manually if I login as jenkins user like this:

```
$ docker exec -it --user=jenkins jenkins /bin/bash
```

I could circle around that using ssh related plugins. But I'm really curious to understand why this happens only with docker images that use Tini as ENTRYPOINT.

**UPDATE1**

I did something like this in /etc/passwd:

`jenkins:x:497:495::/var/jenkins_home:/bin/bash`

and this in /etc/group:

`jenkins:x:495:`

Also tried other *names* like `yesihaveaname` and `yesihaveagroup` instead of `jenkins`

**UPDATE2**

I've been in contact with Tini's [developer](https://github.com/krallin/tini/issues/41) and he does not believe the cause for this problem is Tini as it does not mess around uid or gid, any other leads would be apreciated.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the entries you tried adding to /etc/passwd and /etc/group?

Comment: I have the same issue while trying to pull a gocd-server image from openshift

Comment: Posted also in here: https://github.com/krallin/tini/issues/41

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

**update** 
good to know (this was to easy, so I overlooked this for some time *facepalm*):
To login into a container as root, just give `--user root` to your exec command - like:
 `docker exec -ti -u root mycontainername bash` ... no need to copy passwd file and set pw-hashes ...

---

Like your posted link says, the UserID inside the container maybe has no name allocated.

(Although I do not use Tini... ) I solved this problem as following:

1.) execute INSIDE the container (`docker exec -ti mycontainername sh`):

```
id    # shows the userid (e.g. 1234) and groupid (e.g. 1235) of the current session
```

2.) execute OUTSIDE the container (on the local machine):

```
docker cp mycontainername:/etc/passwd /tmp   # this copies the passwd-file to from inside the container to my local /tmp-directory
echo "somename:x:1234:1235:somename:/tmp:/bin/bash" >> /tmp/passwd   # add some username *!!with the userid and groupid from the output!!* of the `id` command inside the container (CAUTION: do NOT overwrite, do JUST APPEND to the file) - "1234" is just exemplary, do not use it
docker cp /tmp/passwd mycontainername:/etc/passwd   # copy the file back, overwriting the /etc/passwd inside the container
```

Now login to the container (`docker exec -ti mycontainername sh`) again.

*P.S.
If you know the root password of the container you can now switch to root
If you don't have it, you can copy the "/etc/shadow" file out of the container (like above), then edit the root-entry with a known password hash**, then copy it back into the container and then login to the container and run `su`)*

** *to get this password hash on your local system:
(1) add a temporary testuser (`sudo useradd testdumpuser`)
(2) give this user as password (`sudo passwd testdumpuser`)
(3) look in the `/etc/shadow`-file for the "testdumpuser"-entry and copy this long odd string after the first ":" until the second ":"*